Getting specific field from aws-cdk/AwsCustomResource/Lambda resoinse fails
I need to return CertificateArn from lambda for further usage.
My stack:

const generateCertificateCustomResource = new cr.AwsCustomResource(
      this,
      "GenerateCertificateCustomResource",
      {
        onCreate: {
          service: "Lambda",
          action: "invoke",
          parameters: {
            FunctionName: generateCertificateLambda.functionName,
            InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
          },
          physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(uuidv4()),
        },
        policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromStatements([
          new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ["lambda:InvokeFunction"],
            resources: [
              generateCertificateLambda.functionArn,
            ],
          }),
        ]),
      }
    );

    const certificateArn = generateCertificateCustomResource.getResponseField(
      "Payload"
    );

    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "CertificateArn", {
      value: certificateArn,
    });

This logs the output:
{
  "statusCode":200,
  "body":{
    "CertificateArn":"arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:080028499407:certificate/9b676b52-3e52-4ff5-8a7b-03cf57bd7303"
  },
  "CertificateArn":"arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:080028499407:certificate/9b676b52-3e52-4ff5-8a7b-03cf57bd7303"
}

But if I try to get any particular value:
    const certificateArn = generateCertificateCustomResource.getResponseField(
      "Payload.CertificateArn"
    );

I get an error:
CustomResource attribute error: Vendor response doesn't contain Payload.CertificateArn attribute in object
I tried returning this from lambda:
{
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({CertificateArn: "some arn..."}),
}

Also tried but without any success:
    const certificateArn = generateCertificateCustomResource.getResponseField(
      "Payload.body.CertificateArn"
    );


I don't believe you can do this - Payload is considered a string. You can use Fn to use cloudformation itself for parsing if absolutely required - but you might be better off just returning the string without any extra characters from your lambda.

I'm in the same boat here. I find the documentation around this misleading. In all the examples you things like Paramater.Value (SSM) or Buckets.0.Name (S3) or whatever...  but nothing for lambda. It would make so much sense that you could return an object/JSON and have it parse it out, but for the life of me i couldn't solve it either. You can't parse it because its a token, and a run time Payload.foo seems ...  bloody obvious.
So in the end, just return a string from your lambda, retrieve with Payload, and that is about all that is possible. Want more? Spin multiple custom resources
